# Do fibrations preserve limits?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

If I understand correctly, the fourth property [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+fibration#properties) says the following.

> Let $ \begin{smallmatrix}\mathsf C\\ \downarrow\\ \mathsf B
>  \end{smallmatrix}\varphi$ be a cloven fibration and let $D:\mathsf
>  J\to \mathsf C$ be a diagram. Let $(L,\lambda)=\varprojlim
>  (\varphi\circ D)$ (suppose it exists) and define $\tilde D:\mathsf J\to \mathsf
>  \varphi^{-1}(L)$ on objects by $\tilde D(J)=\lambda_J^\ast (DJ)$. Then
>    $\varprojlim \tilde D=\varprojlim D$.

Since $\varprojlim \tilde D$ lies in $\varphi ^{-1}(L)$ we have $\varphi (\varprojlim \tilde D)=L$. But $\varprojlim \tilde D=\varprojlim D $ and so $$\varphi(\varprojlim D)\cong \varprojlim (\varphi\circ D)$$ i.e $\varphi$ preserves limits.

Is this correct? Do fibrations preserve limits? If not, what am I missing here?

Comment: Just because we can build some limits in $\mathsf C$ this way doesn't mean we can build *every* limit in $\mathsf C$ this way.

Comment: @DerekElkins thank you for the response. I am still confused - firstly, is the boxed claim correct as stated? Second, will a fibration indeed preserve limits of this sort? Third, it seems with every diagram $D$ one can associate a $\tilde D$, so why don't all limits upstairs arise this way?

Comment: Yes, the boxed claim is correct. I think, assuming limits exist in $\mathtt B$, preservation of limits follows as you write.

Comment: This does assume essentially that $B$ has the appropriate limits. It seems plausible that you could have a scenario in which $B$ is not complete and $C$ is, and $\varphi\circ D$ has no limit; then clearly limits are not preserved and we don't violate the hypotheses above. But I don't have an example off hand of when that would happen.

Comment: I'm not sure the box claim is correct. Let's try with the easiest diagram, the empty one. Then the box is saying that an object in $\mathsf C$ above a terminal object of $\mathsf B$ which is terminal in its fiber should be terminal in $\mathsf C$. Take any $X$ in $\mathsf C$, surely its image $\varphi X$ has a unique map $\eta: \varphi X \to 1_{\mathsf B}$ to a terminal $1_{\mathsf B}$. Select a terminal object $\star$ inside $\varphi^{-1}(1_{\mathsf B})$: a map $X \to \star$ amonts to a fiber-map $X \to \eta^\ast (\star)$, which has no reason to exists... [to be cont'd]

Comment: [cont'd] ... except if $\eta^\ast$ preserves limit. (This is the case for example if your fibration is actually a bifibration.) I'm pretty sure with can cook a toy counter-example: I let you try with the Grothendieck construction of the functor $(\bullet_1 \to \bullet_2)^{op} \to \mathsf{Cat}$ which sends $\bullet_1$ to the discrete category $\{0,1\}$ and $\bullet_2$ to the terminal category, the image of the unique morphism being the selection of say $0$. Of course all that suppose that when you write $\lim \tilde D$, you are taking the limit of $\tilde D$ inside the fiber at $L$.

Comment: Dear @Pece I am not especially comfortable with fibrations. I am looking for an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2550724/223002) about a particular lemma in Borceux and Janelidze's *Galois Theories*. Perhaps you could help me? Thank you.

Comment: I answered on the other thread. If no one points out a mistake in my comment above, I will make it a proper answer latter with the counterexample fully worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boxed claim seems to be false. In the particular case when $\mathsf J$ is the empty category, it says that an object of the total category is terminal if and only if it is above a terminal object of the base and it is terminal in its own fiber. Below is a counter-example.

Let $C : \mathbf 2^{\rm op} \to \mathsf{Cat}$ be the (pseudo) functor from the opposite of the walking arrow $\mathbf 2 = \{ d \to r \}$ to the 2-category of small categories defined on object as:
$$ d \mapsto \mathbf 2, \quad r \mapsto \mathbf 1$$
(where $1$ is the terminal category) and defined on the unique non identity morphism $d \to r$ as the functor $1 \to 2$ that picks the object $d$ out. The Grothendieck construction $\int C \to \mathbf 2$ is a fibration whose domain can be described as a walking span $x \gets y \to z$, the left leg being mapped to $\mathrm{id}_d$ and the right one to $d\to r$. Clearly $z$ is terminal in its fiber (it is alone!) and above the terminal object $r$ of $\mathbf 2$. But it isn't terminal in $\int C$ because there is no arrow $x \to z$.